# bash adding a filename to an alias command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, alias

I have an alias to a ffmpeg command to start recording a session like this:

```
alias sreq='ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 24 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -qp 0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow'
```

I can just type sreq filename.mkv to start recording. This is pretty good but I'd like to fix this up a bit.

since I always record in .mkv format, how can I have it so that i can avoid having to type `.mkv`

how could I rework this alias command or something so that I can just type `sreq filename` or `sreq /path/to/filename`

and have it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just upgrade the `alias` to a `function`,

e.g

```
function sreq() 
{
   ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 24 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -qp 0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow "$1".mkv
}
```

When you type `sreq /path/to/filename` it would become `ffmpeg ..(redacted)... /path/to/filename.mkv`

Comment: wow, bash is pretty nice!

Comment: This works with almost any bourne-like shell ***if*** you remove the `function` keyword.  The POSIX compliant `dash` shell doesn't understand the `function` keyword, `ksh` understands the `function` keyword sometimes.  Most shells understand `f() { commands; }`.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a function instead of the alias - put this in your .bashrc or .bash_profile -

```
sreq()
{
 ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 24 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -qp 0 -c:v libx264  -preset veryslow $1.mkv
}
```